# serverless with azure functions and webpack

Tags: azure, webpack, azure-functions, serverless-framework, serverless-architecture

I'm wondering if there is anyone using serverless framework with azure functions and how you handle sharing code across functions & bundling?

I'm converting hapi.js app to [serverless](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) + [serverless-azure-functions](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-azure-functions) and I'm trying to bundle my code before deploying so I can use various `require` for reusable modules.

I found [serverless-webpack](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack) and It create bundles that probably works on AWS Lambda but there is a problem on azure because of lack of `function.json` files (ex. `list-function.json`), so the functions aren't visible at all inside azure-portal nor I can't invoke them.

Also found [article](https://cmatskas.com/azure-functions-improvements-with-webpack/) about this problem but It shows how to handle this with `azure-functions-cli` which only support Windows platform.

Best, JH

Answer (score 2):

Giting hints from https://medium.com/a-man-with-no-server/deploying-a-serverless-application-using-webpack-and-babel-to-support-es2015-to-aws-2f61cff8bafb, I modified a serverless azure functions start-up test project with `serverless-webpack`, which seems to be satified with your requirement.

I built a `src` folder in the root directory of serverless azure functions project, as the develop source code folder. With 2 test files:
**`handler.js`**

```
'use strict';
let tool = require("./tool");
/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */

module.exports.hello = function (context) {
  context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

  context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: tool.hello(),
  };

  context.done();
};
```

**`tool.js`**

```
module.exports={
    hello:()=>{
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

`webpack.config.js` in root directory:

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
   entry: './src/handler.js',
   target: 'node',
   externals: [nodeExternals()],
   output: {
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'handler.js', // this should match the first part of function handler in serverless.yml
   },
   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: __dirname,
            loaders: ["babel-loader"]
         }
      ]
   }
};
```

With which configuration file, the out bundled file will be located in `service/handler.js` in root directory.

So I modified `serverless.yml` as well, now it partly looks like:

```
package:
  include:
    - service/handler.js
  exclude:
    - handler.js

functions:
  hello:
    handler: service/handler.hello
    events:
      - http: true
        x-azure-settings:
          authLevel : anonymous
      - http: true
        x-azure-settings:
          direction: out
          name: res

custom:
  webpackIncludeModules:
    packagePath: './package.json'
```

After these modified, use `serverless deploy` will bundle the files in `src` folder then package and deploy to azure function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Big thanks, unfortunettly I got this error.
`./node/NodeTemplatePlugin` same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812204/serverless-webpack-cannot-find-module-node-nodetemplateplugin)

Comment: I use serverless cli to build the project, mentioned at https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/azure/guide/quick-start/. With npm version 5.0.3, node 7.9.0. Didn't meet your issue.